# Dynamically Updating Dependency Injection Service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Background: Asp.Net Core website using Dependency Injection to relay needed services to various parts of the website

I have a service that is being added to the IServiceCollection in the ConfigureServices method in my Startup class as a **singleton** in the following manner:

```
//Settings
services.AddSingleton<ISettingsService, SettingsService>();
services.AddSingleton<ISettingsIO, SettingsIO>();
services.AddSingleton<ISettings>(f =>
{
    return f.GetService<ISettingsService>().GetSettings();
});
```

This works great and all the pages/controllers I need to have access to Example can do so without issue.

However, I now have the capability to change the data that is being pulled in the method GetSettings(). This means that I need to **update** the service that is added to the ServiceCollection.

How can I do this **without** changing the service from a singleton to transient?

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: How is `GetSettings` implemented?

Comment: I don't understand why `ISetting` is also as singleton since `ISettingsService` is allready. Why not use it as transient or scoped and let the `SettingsService` who is singleton resolve it ?

Comment: @YacoubMassad - GetSiteSettings returns an ISiteSettings Object that it creates from a query to the DB.

Comment: @Fabien - Is there something else I would need to do other than simply change the ISettings to AddTransient? I tried that and saw no noticeable changes.

Comment: One way to do it (which might not be the cleanest way to do it) is to make `GetSettings` return a smart implementation of `ISettings`. Such implementation starts with an initial set of settings (the ones from the database) but that can then return a new set of settings. This implementation would provide means for you to set the new settings.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Do you have an example? I'm not terribly concerned with cleanliness, so any solution without switching to a Transient will be sufficient.

Comment: It turns out that there was some code I was unaware of that was basically "caching" the Settings despite them being set as Transient. I ended up turning the service to transient, leaving the "caching" logic in place, and basically hacking in a "refresh" of sorts for the property.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, this is not very clean. I think that a better solution would require more information about your system.

Create a mutable settings wrapper class:

```
public class MyMutableSettings : ISettings
{
    public ISettings Settings {get;set;}

    //Implement the ISettings interface by delegating to Settings, e.g.:
    public int GetNumberOfCats()
    {
        return Settings.GetNumberOfCats();
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
MyMutableSettings mySettings = new MyMutableSettings();

services.AddSingleton<ISettings>(f =>
{
    mySettings.Settings = f.GetService<ISettingsService>().GetSettings();

    return mySettings;
});
```

Then, when you want to change the settings:

```
mySettings.Settings = GetMyNewSettings();
```